# Lint command Error - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, node-modules

After running Yarn Lint command

```
tslint --project tsconfig.json
```

facing below node heap memory issue

```
       FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
124: 0x180b5bf28 start [/usr/lib/dyld]
error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
    122: 0x100cfc4ec node::NodeMainInstance::Run()
```

Please find my tslint.json file

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint-clean-code",
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-no-circular-imports",
    "tslint-config-security",
    "tslint-sonarts"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-commented-out-code": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-use-of-empty-return-value": false,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single",
      "jsx-double",
      "avoid-escape"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": [
      true,
      {
        "multiline": "always",
        "singleline": "never"
      }
    ],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "jsx-no-multiline-js": false,
    "jsx-wrap-multiline": false
  },
  "jsRules": true,
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "storybook/storyLoader.js",
      "bin",
      "lib/*generated.js",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Let me know possible solutions to fix this.
My node version is  **"node": "16.20.2"**